# General equation of a cone

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, projective-geometry, dual-cone

What is the general equation of a cone in $\mathbb{R}^3$ space?

There should be no assumptions about the location of the vertex, direction of the axis or aperture angle, these should all be variable.

Comment: Special case: U=O https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4543514/ellipsoid-equation-of-intersection-of-a-cone-and-a-hyperplane/4544084?noredirect=1#comment9555502_4544084

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A point X (where $X = [x,y,z]^T$ ) on a cone  will satisfy: 
$$(X-U)^TM(X-U) = 0,$$
where $U$ is the vertex of the cone ,  $\hat{D}$ is the axis of the cone (unit vector) and,
$$ M = \hat{D}\hat{D}^T - \cos^2(\alpha)I_{3 \times 3},$$
where $\alpha$ is the aperture angle of the cone and $I$ is the identity matrix.