# General Equation for Parabola in 3D space

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

It is well known that the Cartesian equation for a general parabola in 2D space is 
$$(Ax+Cy)^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$$
or in parametric form, 
$$(at^2+bt+c, pt^2+qt+r)$$

> - What is the Cartesian system of equations for a general parabola in 3D space?
> - Is there a matrix representation?
> - What is the parametric form?
> - What is the aperture?

Comment: Curves in 3D space can’t in be represented by a single implicit Cartesian equation. You need a system of equations or a parameterization similar to the one you’re already got.

Comment: @amd The question has been reworded to reflect this more accurately. Thanks.

Comment: There’s not really a matrix representation for the same reason that you need a system of equations: each defines a *surface*.

Comment: This seems relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1957430

Answer (score 3):

There is no "canonic" way to give a Cartesian system of equations for a parabola in 3D space. The simplest and oldest way is that of giving a parabola as intersection between a plane and a cone, [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2368523/find-two-points-and-one-angle-so-that-cone-intersects-the-xy-plane-in-the-para/2369432#2369432) for an example.

On the other hand, the locus of points whose distance from a given line (directrix) is the same as their distance from a given point (focus) is a [parabolic cylinder](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParabolicCylinder.html), so you may find more natural to give the parabola as the intersection between this cylinder and the plane of focus and directrix.

Answer (score 2):

The projections of the parabola on the coordinate planes are also parabolas. 
Hence you can expect the parametric equations

$$(at^2+bt+c,dt^2+et+f,gt^2+ht+i).$$

For an implicit equation, you can use a linear change of coordinates

$$\begin{pmatrix}u\\v\\w\end{pmatrix}=T\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}$$ and the system

$$\begin{cases}(Au+Cv)^2+Du+Ev+f=0,\\w=0.\end{cases}$$

This is the intersection of a parabolic cylindre and a plane.