# Equation of the section of a cone

Tags: conic-sections, projective-geometry

My purpose is to start from a plane $\pi$ of equation $z=ax+ by +c$ that intersects a cone $\kappa$ of equation $x^2+ y^2= k^2 z^2$ and  find, analytically, the equation of the conic (intersection of the two surfaces), in a reference system in the plane $\pi$, so that this equation can be compared to the classical   equation of a conic :
 $$Ax^2 + 2Bxy + Cy^2 + 2Dx+ 2Ey +F=0  \quad (1) $$
in a way that make explicit the link between the parameters $a,b,c$ of the plane $\pi$ and the  matrix  that gives the conic:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}x&y&1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
A&B&D\\
B&C&E\\
D&E&F
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\1\end{bmatrix}=0
$$

To simplify a bit, take $k=1$ so that the intersection of the plane and the cone gives:
$$
\begin {cases}
z=ax+by+c\\
x^2(a^2-1)+y^2(b^2-1)+2abxy+2acx+2bcy+c^2=0
\end{cases}
$$
The second equation seems the searched equation, but I think that really it is the equation of the conic  **projected** on the plane $z=0$.

If we want the equation **referred to the plane** $\pi$how we can proceed from this?

Comment: Either you perform a rotation carrying your plane to  $xy$ plane, or you geometrically find the parameters of the conic.

Comment: Related? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2770840/general-equation-for-parabola-in-3d-space

Comment: @Aretino. In what reference system on the plane $\pi$ I have to express the parameters of the conic?

Comment: @user170231: Thank you. But not so related :(

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha$ be the given plane and $\vec n=(-a,-b,1)$ its normal vector. Let then $\theta$ and $\phi$ be the angles formed by $\vec n$ with $z$-axis and by its projection on the $xy$ plane with $x$-axis. 
The matrices performing rotations by an angle $\phi$ about $z$-axis and by an angle $\theta$ about $y$-axis are respectively:
$$
R_1=\pmatrix{
\cos\phi & \sin\phi & 0 \\
-\sin\phi & \cos\phi & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
}
\quad\text{and}\quad
R_2=\pmatrix{
\cos\theta & 0 & -\sin\theta \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\sin\theta & 0 & \cos\theta \\
},
$$
where:
$$
\cos\phi=-\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}},\quad
\sin\phi=-\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}},\quad
\cos\theta=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a^2+b^2}},\quad
\sin\theta=\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{\sqrt{1+a^2+b^2}}.
$$
Matrix $R=R_2\circ R_1$ represents then a rotation carrying then $\vec n$ on $z$-axis, while the intersection line between $\alpha$ and $xy$ plane is transformed to a line parallel to $y$-axis.
We can compute $R$ and check that it transforms plane $-ax-by+z=c$ to plane 
$\displaystyle z=\frac{c}{\sqrt{1+a^2+b^2}}$, while cone $x^2+y^2=k^2z^2$ is transformed to
$$
\left(a^2+b^2+1\right)y^2 +
\left(1-k^2 \left(a^2+b^2\right)\right)x^2 
+2 \left(k^2+1\right)\sqrt{a^2+b^2} x z
+ \left(a^2+b^2-k^2\right)z^2 =0.
$$
Substituting here $\displaystyle z=\frac{c}{\sqrt{1+a^2+b^2}}$ one then gets the equation of the conic section:
$$
\left(a^2+b^2+1\right)y^2 -\left(k^2\left(a^2+b^2\right)-1\right)x^2 
+2 c \left(k^2+1\right)\sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2}{a^2+b^2+1}} x
+\frac{c^2 \left(a^2+b^2-k^2\right)}{a^2+b^2+1}=0.
$$
The origin of this coordinate system on plane $\alpha$ is 
$O'= \displaystyle \frac{c}{\sqrt{1+a^2+b^2}}(-a,-b,1)$, that is the projection of $O$ on $\alpha$, while $y$-axis is parallel to the intersection between $\alpha$ and $xy$ plane.

Comment: Thank You ! I'm verifying and I have a doubt: We don't have to use  $R=R_2^{-1}R_1^{-1}$?

Comment: Anyway, I'm searching an equation that have all terms so that I can also go back from $Ax^2+2BXY+CY^2+2DX+2Ey+F=0$ to the plane that generate the conic. Ths means that the symmetry axis of the conic have to stay on the line of maximum slope of the plane $z=ax+by+c$. (Si capisce cosa cerco? Non trovo libri in cui sia trattato questo problema.)

Comment: Of course, equations are transformed by substituting $(x,y,z)$ with $R^{-1}(x,y,z)$, where $R^{-1}=R_1^{-1}\circ R_2^{-1}$.

Comment: If your problem is that of finding the position of the generating cone, given the equation of a conic in $xy$ plane, then you'd better state that in your question.

Comment: See also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2651714/from-ellipse-equation-to-circular-cone-axis/2651961#2651961 and here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2351662/origin-centred-elliptical-spotlight-with-conical-light-source-of-fixed-apertur