# ellipsoid equation of intersection of a cone and a hyperplane

Tags: geometry

I have the equation of an cone $C$ and its axis of cone, locating its apex on the origin.
desired the ellipsoid which is the intersection of $C$ with a hyperplane parallel to (x,y) plane and in height of $h_t$. Anyone can help finding the ellipsoid equation which is bold painted in the picture? The follwings are some assumptions that I've made, and a picture depicting my question better.

$$t = (t_x, t_y, z), \qquad z = h_t$$
$$\frac{h_t}{h_i} = \frac{l^{\prime\prime}}{l} \rightarrow {l^{\prime\prime}} = \frac{h_t \times l}{h_i}$$
$$t_x = L^{\prime\prime} \times \cos \gamma +x_{X_0}$$
$$t_y = L^{\prime\prime} \times \sin \gamma +y_{X_0}$$

[image]

Comment: Not an ellipsoid (a volume) but plainly an ellipse (a curve)

Comment: This is raised from a special case that we know for sure that is an ellipsoid.

Comment: $3D$ rotational matrices are beyond human. They are very difficult. We saw them in robotics course in M.Sc.

Comment: **nD text vs. 3D drawing** without any explanation. Don't you think you should say what are x,y,z in an nD context ? Is z for example not remaining a single axis but representing (n-2) dimensions... ?

Comment: @JeanMarie the problem is in 3D. A point is shown with (x,y,z) vector.

Comment: Therefore, I maintain that you have two non-adequate names in your title : hyperplane $\to$ (affine) plane, [ellipsoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid) $\to$ ellipse.

Comment: @JeanMarie You are right. I'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the figure, the *unit* directing vector of the axis of the cone is :
$$\vec{V} = \begin{pmatrix}\sin \beta \cos \gamma \\ \sin \beta \sin \gamma \\ \cos \beta \end{pmatrix}$$

Let $M(x,y,z)$ be the coordinates of the generic point of the cone. We express it by saying that the dot product :
$$\vec{OM}.\vec{V}=\|\vec{OM}\|\underbrace{\|\vec{V}\|}_1 \cos \alpha$$

Otherwise said, the cone's equation is:

$$x \ \underbrace{\sin \beta \cos \gamma}_a + y 
\ \underbrace{\sin \beta \sin \gamma}_b + z 
\ \underbrace{\cos \beta}_c \ = \ \cos \alpha\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$

that can be squared : we get in this way the two parts of the cone (even if we need only the first one):

$$(xa+yb+zc)^2 \ = \ (\cos^2 \alpha)(x^2+y^2+z^2)\tag{1}$$

Now, the intersection of the cone with the plane with equation $z=h_t$ is easily done by replacing $z$ by constant $h_t$ in (1). The result is indeed the equation of a conic curve.

Can you end the study from here ?

Comment: Any comment ?...

Answer (score 0):

We can find the equation of the cone by the well-known
$\vec{u}\bullet\vec{v}=\Vert\vec{u}\Vert\Vert\vec{v}\Vert\cos\theta$.

I will not use your notations, completely. I didn't understand them. Anyway...

Let $T=(t_x,t_y,t_z)$ be a point on the axis of your cone whose apex is the origin. Then the direction vector of the cone is $\vec{T}$ and lets say that the general point on the cone is $X(x,y,z)$. Then the equation of the cone is just $\vec{T}\bullet\vec{X}=\Vert\vec{T}\Vert\Vert\vec{X}\Vert\cos\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is the openning angle of the cone. This gives,
$$A^2(x^2+y^2+z^2)=(t_x x+t_y y+t_z z)^2\tag{1}$$
where $A=\sqrt{t_x^2+t_y^2+t_z^2}\cos\alpha$.
You wanted to find the equation of the elipse obtained after cutting this cone with the plane $z=t_z$. Then, we just substitute this in $(1)$ and find,
$$(A^2-t_x^2)x^2-2t_xt_yxy+(A^2-t_y^2)y^2-2t_xt_z^2x-2t_yt_z^2y+A^2z_t^2-z_t^4=0\tag{2}$$
So, the solution is $z=t_z$ and $(2)$. It is not easy to find the center and foci of this ellipse due to cross term with $xy$.

Let me give a simple examples.

1. Let $T=(0,0,1)$ then $A=\cos\alpha$ and the ellipse is $x^2+y^2=\tan^2\alpha$, a circle.
2. Degenerate case. Let $T=(0,1,1)$ and $\alpha=0$. Then $A=\sqrt{2}$ and the ellipse is $2x^2+(y-1)^2=0$ which is only the point $T(0,1,1)$.

Better examples can be given.

Comment: Not fundamentaly different from my answer, don't you think ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1834068/general-equation-of-a-cone